# How to dynamically calculate Gap & Over & YTD in Target column Power BI

Tags: dynamic, max, powerbi

**Goal**
My Goal is creating a measure or customise column to show how much Gap & Over achieve compare with target then apply on stacked column chart.

The problems is data have more than 1 dimension , if we did that on raw data before import , the report cannot show the correct calculation when we choose overall while ignoring sub-level.

```
data
TYPE_Layer_1    TYPE_Layer_2    TGT YTD YTD in TGT  GAP OVER
A               orange          100 100 100          0  0
A               apple            50 30  30          20  0
B               orange          120 135 120          0  15
B               apple            60 55  55           5  0
C               orange          130 140 130          0  10
C               apple            70 70  70           0  0
```

Origin data shape show only the gap over and YTD in target by Type Layer 1 + Type Layer 2 ,
but the wrong Gap or Over figures show when we sum only Type layer 1:

```
TYPE_Layer_1    TGT YTD YTD in TGT  GAP OVER
B               180 190 175           5 15
```

**Problem**
The total of B's Over achieve should be 10 and no Gap but it still show gap 5 & over as 15

```
Formula in Excel
C = Target , D = YTD
YTD in TGT
=if(C2-D2>=0,D2,if(C2-D2<0,C2))
GAP
=max(C2-D2,0)
OVER
=max(D2-C2,0)
```

How to achieve this whatever by Measure of Customise column in Power BI ?

tested that not dynamic seems need more formula :

```
GAP = MAXX(D_PBI,D_PBI[TGT]-D_PBI[YTD])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simple. Define these measures.

```
// Measures
Total TGT  = SUM ( Data[TGT] )
Total YTD  = SUM ( Data[YTD] )
YTD in TGT = MIN ( [Total YTD], [Total TGT] )
GAP        = MAX ( [Total TGT] - [Total YTD], 0 )
OVER       = MAX ( [Total YTD] - [Total TGT], 0 )
```

This will produce the expected results at any drill-down level.

[image: Result 1]
[image: Result 2]
[image: Result 3]
[image: Result 4]

Comment: Thankyou. Why i cannot create another measure : Total of YTD_in_TGT_GAP_OVER = sum([YTD in TGT],[GAP],[OVER]) , on the measure just created on your approach ? * For applying invisible line to display total label .

Comment: Because SUM accepts only one argument and it must be a column reference, such as Data[TGT]. [YTD in TGT], [GAP], and [OVER] are scalar expressions. You can use ‘+’ operator instead.